# Inserting a line to a known block of text

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I define a 'block' of text as all lines between start of file, newline or end of file:

```
block1
block2
block3

anotherblock4
anotherblock5
anotherblock6

lastblock7
lastblock8
```

Any text can occupy a block - it is unknown what lines are there.
I tried to write a shell script to insert a new line at the 2nd block, but since sed doesn't like working with newlines, I hacked around this sed oneliner:

```
sed -n "H;\${g;s/\n\n/\nTEST\n\n/2;p}"
```

This results into:

```
[newline]
block1
block2
block3

anotherblock4
anotherblock5
anotherblock6
TEST

lastblock7
lastblock8
```

The problem is, it adds a newline to the start of the buffer (marked as [newline] because StackOverflow's markup cannot show it)
Is there another way to do it using a different tool or different regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want and gets rid of the unwanted `newline` at the beginning:

```
sed -n "1{x;d};H;\${g;s/\n\n/\nTEST\n\n/2;p}"
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one possible solution

```
awk '/^$/{f++}f==2{print "TEST\n";f=0;next}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't my proudest moment, but I think it does what you want... Maybe? I wasn't able to get `sed` to do anything useful as, at least on my machine, it doesn't like working with newlines in an `s/x/y` substitution command.

```
# cat blocks
block1
block2
block3

anotherblock4
anotherblock5
anotherblock6

lastblock7
lastblock8
# python -c 'import sys,re; print re.sub("(\n\n[\s\S]*?\n)(\n)", "\\1TEST\n\\2", sys.stdin.read(), 1),' < blocks
block1
block2
block3

anotherblock4
anotherblock5
anotherblock6
TEST

lastblock7
lastblock8
```

Notes:

- There's no equivalent of `sed`'s "replace the *2nd* match" option, so I needed a more complicated regex.
- `.` doesn't match newlines, thus `[\s\S]`.
- The `?` makes the `*` non-greedy.
- The 4th parameter of `1` limits this to a single replacement.
- The comma at the end inhibits `print` from adding an extra newline.

---

Alternatively, you could tack "`| tail +2`" on after the almost-but-not-quite-right `sed` command to chop off the first line of output.

Comment: You mean '| tail -c +2'? That is my current workaround. I'm looking into educating myself better into sed and bash in general.

Answer (score 0):

One more `awk` solution.  This asks `awk` to keep track of paragraphs instead of counting them yourself like ghostdog74's solution.

```
awk -v 'RS=\n\n' '{print}NR==2{print"TEST"}{print""}'
```

Comment: this solution was presented as well, but it will add a newline at the last block and someone(i think its the author) commented on that.